# Como remover loop de redirecionamento no Wp?

Tags: wordpress

Estou tentando instalar o wordpress em um subdominio porém estou recebendo um erro:

> Esta página da web tem um loop de redirecionamento
>
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso? já procurei muito no google e não acho uma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro verifique se o domínio configurado no `WordPress` está correto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se estiver com problemas no acesso ao Painel, pode adicionar as configurações no o arquivo `wp-config.php` e subir via `FTP` :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Se ainda assim não funcionar, recomendo desativar todos os `plugins` instalados, e verificar se o problema foi resolvido. E caso não resolva, sugiro contactar um suporte à hospedagem pois pode ser um problema conhecido do `Apache`.